# The low tag is such a low quality tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Let's burninate the [low](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low) tag. The tag is far too vague.

There are 7 questions tagged with it so far. Out of these 7:

- Two relate to low fluids (oil, fuel etc)
- One relates to a quiet horn [electrical](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical)
- Two relate to low idle problems
- One is a closed, off topic question.

I suggest removing the low tag as the existing tags [fuel](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuel), [oil](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil) and [idle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idle) cover all these questions.

Comment: Good call on this.

Comment: Just as a follow-up ... it is now fully burninated. No longer shows up in the tag list.